# How to use LIKE operator in WMI queries?

Tags: powershell, wmi

I try to get info about DHCP Leases via WMI, so I use this code: `gwmi -ComputerName dhcp -query "select DHCPLeaseExpires, ipaddress from Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration"`, but I'd like to make condition more precise. I'd like to filter all rows with certain IPAddress in it.

For example, I have this output:

```
DHCPLeaseExpires :
IPAddress        :
PSComputerName   :

DHCPLeaseExpires : 20200603123623.000000+120
IPAddress        : {172.21.0.100}
PSComputerName   :

DHCPLeaseExpires : 20200603123623.000000+120
IPAddress        : {10.10.10.10, fe80::cc09:dfe8:d8b8:99f8}
PSComputerName   :
```

How can I use LIKE operator to filer out all entries but 10.10.10.10?

Tried this: `gwmi -ComputerName dhcp -query "select DHCPLeaseExpires, ipaddress from Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration where IPAddress like '%10%'"`
but got InvalidArgument error. Also tried `"%10%"`, `\"%10%\"`, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IPAddress is an Array.

So you could use `Where-Object` with `-contains` or `-notcontains`

For instance like this:

```
gwmi -ComputerName dhcp -query "select DHCPLeaseExpires, ipaddress from Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration" | 
    Where-Object IPAddress -contains 10.10.10.10
```